# Can any tree be converted to an R-tree?

Tags: tree, r-tree, tree-structure

Is it possible, in theory, to convert any tree into an R-tree? For example, let's say I have a tree of nodes each characterized by an id, value and N features. Does it make sense to convert this to an (N+2) dimensional R-tree? How would that impact search time and tree size on disk? What happens if the number of features is not constant for each node?

Comment: This probably belongs on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tree is *not balanced*, or doesn't have a controlled *fanout*, it won't be a proper R-tree.

Of course you can compute MBRs, and it will become a "nested rectangles tree". But there is more to an R-tree than just using rectangles; a key point of the R-tree is to be *balanced*.

It does clearly not make much sense to put the ID in as an additional feature. This will not lead to sensible *splits*. You can of course store the ID, but I'd not use it for indexing.

You really should consider the *queries* you want to do. **Any index must be appropriate for your queries, not just for your data**!